# Call back function with delay using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I use jquery call back function to removeClass, Now I want to attach delay with this function. My function is

```
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
$('.mydiv').find('.div1').addClass('jmnew').show('slow', function(){
$('.mydiv').find('.jmnew').removeClass('jmnew');
});
});
});
```

HTML//

```
<div class="mydiv">
<div class="div1" style="display:none">
abc
</div>
<a href="#">click me</a>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAHYW/) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout`

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('.mydiv').find('.div1').addClass('jmnew').show('slow', function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.mydiv').find('.div1').removeClass('jmnew')
            },2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `setTimeout` function, since jQuery's `delay()` only works with queued effects.

```
$(function() {

    $('a').click(function() {
        $('.mydiv').find('.div1').addClass('jmnew').show('slow', function() {

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.mydiv').find('.jmnew').removeClass('jmnew')
            }, 1000);
        })
    })
})​
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqkLc/).